# CiviRule Minute Delay not working

Tags: civirules

I've created a few rules with CiviRules that trigger an email. They all work perfectly as long as I don't add a delay.
I've tested adding a 1-minute delay with different types of rules but the email never gets triggered?

The job appears in the civicrm_queue_item table but doesn't get released

The job log for CiviRules delayed actions says success

Using CiviCRM 4.7.27 and CiviRules 1.15

I did further testing on my local environment and it works as expected when I changed the site's timezone to the one I live in.

Update: The emails were sent in the end but 11 hrs later even though the release date was correctly set to 1 minute later in the civicrm_queue_item table

Answer (score 2):

The scheduled job for delayed civirules (Process delayed civirule actions (Always)) should be set to always. Can you check if your cron properly executes the CiviCRM scheduled jobs?

Comment: It is set for always. Even when I run it manually it won't trigger up the action. It just ran regularly with cron 11 hours later

Comment: timezone issue?

Comment: It is not an issue that I recognise. I use the minute delay regularly without any problems?

Answer (score 1):

You could try upgrading to the latest CiviRules version? I recommend doing this on a test version first and always backing up your existing rules before you do.